# How to deploy windows form application with entity framework

Tags: vb.net

I am busy developing my own application, it uses a sql server database and it is connected through an entity framework. I use store procedures to insert, update, delete, select from my database.

The app works perfect on my machine even when I publish it. But my problem comes in when I try to install the app to my friend’s computer. It crashes and does not start because it cannot connect to the database.

Is there a way to publish my app with the database, without importing all the tables, store procedures and database into my friend’s pc? I just want to make it so the user just has to install the app and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your app relies on the db to work, so if you want to put it on your friends PC then you need to make the DB available somewhere, whether it be a local copy or a copy stored on a server somewhere running SQL.

How are you storing your connection string?  Is it hard coded in the app or are you utilising the app.config file?  To do what you're trying to do you'll need to put the connection string into the app.config file, so you can change it depending on the installation.

**either that or**

if you want to run your app without data, put a demo flag or something into the app.config file.  Put some code into your app to check this value, if it's true then bypass the SQL code and maybe supply some demo data which is hard coded.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I am using an app.config file, what will i have to change in there to be able to change on installation? Is there another program that i could use to copy over the database? Like using SQL CE. It will be a waste of hard drive space to install SQL SERVER on my friends machine.

Comment: yeah SQL CE or even create a MySQL version of your db.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQL CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact), but you may find it a little more difficult to 'design' your database in it if you are more used to working in SQL Server.

Have you considered SQL Server Express as an option?

On the connection string issue, you can now get the data connection wizard that Microsoft use in Visual Studio via Nuget; this makes adding a way to dynamically configure connection strings on your clients machine much easier.

Lastly, connection strings for the entity framework are different from standard SQL connection strings. Make sure that you clearly understand the differences before you start trying to configure them programmatically. Julie Lerman's excellent book on the Entity Framework explains the differences well.